# Bitmap height not matching ImageView height even though set to same value

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a cardview with an ImageView aligned to bottom left.

[image]

I am getting the height of the ImageView and setting it as the height of the bitmap.

```
iv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height = iv.getMeasuredHeight();

            Paint widthPaint = new Paint();
            widthPaint.setTextSize(200f);
            float width = widthPaint.measureText(text);

            Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width + S.dpToPx(ctx, 20), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(220, 244, 244, 244));
            paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
            paint.setTextSize(200f);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            canvas.drawText(text, canvas.getWidth() / 2, (canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2), paint);

            iv.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
        }
    });
```

The output of both `iv.getMeasuredHeight();` and `bmOverlay.getHeight()` is 120. But the bitmap is not covering the ImageView. I cannot understand why.

XML of the ImageView.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rquiz_iv_topic"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Comment: android:scale_type = "fitxy"

Comment: can you past your layout code because i don't thing scale type will help you in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your imageview set scaleType="centerInside" and adjustViewBounds="true".

```
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rquiz_iv_topic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"            
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />
```

Refer for more details [ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: this is a method of scaling. But why is bitmap height and the imageview height being the same scaling is necessary?

Comment: I understand your answer...my point is that I didn't want scaling so I made the bitmap height of the imageview. It doesn't work properly without the scaling.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to archive: **Set ImageView exactly size with the Bitmap** is something wrong.

You needs to fits all the phone screen instead of settings it View by pixel.

**You can:**

**1. Respect Parent Way**:
Put `ImageView` in `LinearLayout`, Set Weight as `0.5` (means fits 50% of `LinearLayout`), and set related (Vertical or Horizontal) Height or Width to `0dp`(to let `Layout Manager` to handles the size).

And, set your image scale to `fitXY` / `centerCrop`.(Or you can try other scaling)

2.**Respect Bitmap Way**:
Put `ImageView` in `RelativeLayout`, set other nearby Views to stand with `ImageView` by `layout_alignBottom`/`layout_alignLeft` etc. And set `ImageView` Height and/or Width to `wrap_content`, let the Layout handles the size.